# Mid- and lowband frequency response of CE

Tags: frequency-response

I'd like to derive an expression for the small signal voltage gain \$A(s)=V_o/V_{sig}\$ that applies in the mid- and low frequency bands.
I know that for a CE the voltage gain would be:

\$A_v = -g_mR_c/(1+g_mR_E)\$

Does that mean that \$A(s)\$ could easily be found by simply substituting \$R_E=R_e+1/sC_E\$?

[image]

Comment: looks correct to me

Comment: @analogsystemsrf what would be the bode plots for the gain magnitude \$|A_M|\$, given that \$I=0.25mA,R_c=10K\Omega,C_E=10\mu F,R_e=0\$. I found that \$|A_M|=40dB\$ for these values and \$f_L=159Hz\$. Now I'm asked to plot the bode plots for this gain and for the case where \$R_e=400\Omega\$ which yields a gain \$|A_M|=26.02dB\$ and \$f_L=31.8Hz\$. Would it comprise two rising slopes, the one for 40dB with greater slope than the one for 26.02dB, stabilizing at 40dB and 26.02dB respectively and at frequencies 159Hz and 31.8Hz respectively?